TypeError: 'GraphModule' object is not subscriptable (Access Weights for .onnx ML model in Pytorch)
I have a popular .onnx ML model for weather forecasting and am trying to convert this to PyTorch for finetuning. I use the following code to convert this:
import os
import numpy as np
import onnx
from onnx import numpy_helper
import onnxruntime as ort
from onnx2torch import convert

model_24 = onnx.load('pangu_weather_24.onnx')
tm = convert(model_24) #Convert onnx model to torch

From here, I want to access the weights of the model in the 'tm' object but I can't seem to find any resources online for this.
Trying to subscript it with tm[0] reveals the following error:
TypeError: 'GraphModule' object is not subscriptable

and the dict for this object via 'tm.dict' is even more confusing (pasted in the image).
The normal methods online for accessing a PyTorch weight matrix also reveal the same error that the graphmodule is not subscriptable

PanguWeather Link: https://github.com/198808xc/Pangu-Weather
Portion of the output of the tm.dict here:
;  b1_mul_376 = b1_constant_3292 = None\n    b1_constant_3293 = getattr(self, "b1/Constant_3293")()\n    b1_mul_377 = getattr(self, "b1/Mul_377")(b1_reshape_321, b1_constant_3293);  b1_reshape_321 = b1_constant_3293 = None\n    b1_constant_3294 = getattr(self, "b1/Constant_3294")()\n    b1_add_57 = getattr(self, "b1/Add_57")(b1_mul_377, b1_constant_3294);  b1_mul_377 = b1_constant_3294 =

You can access its weights normally through tm.parameters() just like any nn.Module()

What code would I use to access the weights via tm.parameters()? When I print tm.parameters(), it spits out a similar output to tm.dict (i.e. just the name of each layer). Thanks

One potential solution I found later on using .children():
for layer in tm.children():
    print(layer.state_dict())

